# Selecting physical solutions in numerical eigenvalue problems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue, numerical-method

I try to solve a certain time-independent Schrodinger equation numerically, using the method of [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). My boundary conditions are such that the finite difference method gives me an eigenvalue problem of the form 
$$
V A = \lambda A,
$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

However, from calculations that I do, I know the behavior of my wavefunction in the region of interest. This specific behavior corresponds only to one of the calculated eigenvalues. Moreover, the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a function of the system's energy $E$, specifically it is proportional to $E^2$. But, only the above-mentioned eigenvalue will give me a real value of the energy $E$.

Is it correct to say that the only physical solution corresponds to this eigenvalue, even though the mathematical problem gives more solutions?

Comment: I think your title is a little misleading to your text (the title seems to indicate you are having a problem with the numerics whereas the question is about the correspondence of physical solution with multiple mathematical solutions); you may want to consider modifying the title to reflect your question more accurately

Comment: I just updated the title of the question. I think now it corresponds better to the context! Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Are you saying that there should be only one eigenstate (wavefunction) that is a physical solution to this problem, or are you saying that there are many solutions but only one you care about?

Comment: The mathematical problem gives me a lot of eigenvalues. (It depends on the dimensions of the matrix). However, from an analysis that I have done, although I do not know the exact energy eigenvalue, I know that it has to be smaller than a specific quantity so that I have bound states. The solutions I get contain this value, but also all the others for which I do not longer have bound states.